# Where to obtain ipython kernspec for Python 2.7

Tags: python, ipython

I'd like to work with Python 2.7 using Jupyter, but it doesn't come up as an option when I click to create a new notebook.

I read that I need to install the ipython 2.7 kernspec file, but I get this error:

```
$ ipython2.7 kernelspec install-self
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/frontend.py:30: UserWarning: The top-level `frontend` package has been deprecated. All its subpackages have been moved to the top `IPython` level.
  warn("The top-level `frontend` package has been deprecated. "
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | File not found: u'kernelspec'
```

What is the "correct" way to obtain this file for Ubuntu 14.04?

Also I'm drawing a blank looking for documentation - is there any?

I installed Jupyter by running:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ipython3 ipython3-notebook
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try the answers from that [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28831854/how-do-i-add-python3-kernel-to-jupyter-ipython) on SO?

Comment: Do you mean run `sudo pip3 install python[all]`? 
Is that the "correct" way, or just "a" way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it was because my version of ipython was different as it was installed with aptitude instead of pip. I saw that with :

```
sudo pip uninstall ipython
Not uninstalling ipython at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, owned by OS
```

so I uninstalled this version and reinstalled it with pip :

```
sudo apt-get remove ipython
sudo pip install ipython
```

and then you can install the python2 kernel and check it works :

```
sudo ipython kernelspec install-self
ipython kernelspec list
```

**Note : you may want to use the option --user with pip if you want to avoid install as root**